What is the real transmission speed in UART?
I'm trying to transmit data at 6.144 Mbit/s through the UART port of Nucleo-H723ZG microcontroller. For reading on the PC, I'm using Free Device Monitoring Studio. Based on my UART parameters, I should be receiving data at 6.144 MBit/s, but what I'm actually receiving on the PC is only 2.4 Mbit/s.
Here is a screenshot of an 11 second recording that I made:

Here the STMCubeIDE parameters:

And here are the parameters I configured in the software tool:

I'm not performing any memory management in the MCU. The only code is for receiving the data from SAI (Serial Audio Interface) and transmitting it to the UART port, as shown in the image:

I'm wondering if the issue is due to a software error in the microcontroller or if there are limitations in the serial reading on the PC. Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

Do you have a scope or a logic analyzer, to measure the bit timing? Bottlenecks can exist in every layer of your stack - PC, Hardware or embedded SW.

PPP seems really wrong.  It's for encapsulating ethernet over the top of a serial port, not for generic serial communications.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Your functions appear to be blocking and not interrupt / DMA driven. That means you will receive 16 bytes on the audio port (and do nothing else in that time) and then transmit 16 bytes on the UART (and do nothing else in that time). You can see the code for the HAL_UART_TRANSMIT in this question.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72041049/how-hal-uart-transmit-it-manages-sending-data-on-serial-on-the-stm32f091vb First answer, scroll down to 'blocking'

I was running out of characters. The way I would handle this is using DMA and ping pong buffers. See https://audiodsplab.wordpress.com/ping-pong-buffer-audio-stream/

You write  6.144 Mbit/s, but you configured 6875000? Baud rate should be exactly the same on both sides. I don't believe that such a high speed transmission is possible without hardware flow control. When you receive 2.4 MBit/s what about lost characters, receiver overrun? Do you receive exactly the same test data as you have sent? If you transfer from one PC to another PC, what is the highest possible data rate without any error?

Also, if your recording tool shows "effective bytes of application received", don't forget to multiply by 10/8 = 1.25 (que to start/stop bit).

@Uwe The baud rates match. You don't need to match baud rate to what you want to send as long as the baud rate is higher. In which case it isn't, if your data rate is 6144 kbps and UART bitrate is 6875 kbps which can only transfer 5500 kbps of your payload.

What are you using as UART on the PC and can it do 6875000 bps? It may be very rare rate. I use 12 Mbps between MCU and PC USB UART chipset and it works fine. Your PC UART may be incapable of either the specific baud rate or that rate of actual data sent.

Your desired communication speed have to meet equation from 53.5.7 USART baud rate generation in Reference manual.
Baudrate = USART_kernel_clock / USARTDIV
where USARTDIV is integer and must be higher then 16. If you select oversampling to 8 samples, then equation becomes to
Baudrate = 2*USART_kernel_clock / USARTDIV
Which is more suitable for high communication speeds.
Space of available baudrates is spares in range of high buadrates. Imagine that your USART_kernel_clock is 120MHz. Then with oversamplig 8, you can select USARTDIV to 39 and speed will be 6.154Mb/s which is close enought to be tolerated. If you select USARTDIV to 40 your baudrate will be 6Mb/s. Nothing between theese two numbers !
If you need to be more flexible with choosing baudrates you can also clock USART directly from PLL.

The register value calculation is not that straightforward. In 16x mode it might be but in 8x mode you have only 3 selector bits for the fractional baud rate generator and bit 3 must be zero so divisor of 40 is invalid. Also to transmit 6.144 Mbps worth of payload data you need the UART to have at least 7.68 Mbps due to start&stop bits, preferably higher. Depending on the PC side, it might not be select any arbitrary baud rate but 8, 10 or 12 Mbps could be possible common rates on both the STM32 and PC.

You are right, baudrates selection is also limited by 3rd bit of USARTDIV. It is not clear what type of device is recieveing that data. If it is ordinary USB-UART Bridge (FTDI etc.) then baudrate selection is limited like you write and moreover there will be need for hardware flow control and bridge have to be equiped with USB 2.0 High speed.
